# XOR 128 bit bitsets

Tags: c++, bitset

I am trying to XOR tow 128 bit bitsets.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bitset>

int main()
{
  std::bitset<128> testing;
  testing = std::bitset<128>(0x544F4E20776E69546F656E772020656F) ^
  std::bitset<128>(0x5473206768204B20616D754674796E75);
  std::cout<<testing;
}
```

The output I get is 
[image]

The first 64 bits are 0 and the last 64 bits are XOR. I also get a compiler warning

```
warning: integer constant is too large for its type
```

Is there some way to XOR 128 bit bitsets or do I need to create an ugly hack?

Comment: No native C++ type on today's normal machines is capable of holding a 128 bit value. You could store two `std::bitset<64>`s and chain them together.

Comment: Is there anything available in BOOST C++ @cad

Comment: @PranavKapoor No idea of Boost but there's probably a compiler built-in available.

Comment: Boost won't help you with literals like `0x544F4E20776E69546F656E772020656F`. You just can't do this this easily.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is not the XOR, but initializing the bitsets from a constant. As the warning says, there is a limit to the size that integer constants can have, and `std::bitset` constructor takes an `unsigned long long` which is usually 64 bits long.

You can initialize the bitsets from a binary string instead:

```
std::bitset<128>("100101010....")
```

Or combine it from two 64-bit bitsets:

```
std::bitset<128> value = (std::bitset<128>(0x1234567890123456) << 64) | 
                         std::bitset<128>(0x1234567890123456);
```